# What is the best way to see if an array has two objects with the same values for two distinct properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, set

For example, I want to see if this array has two objects with the same first name and last name.

```
[{fName: Albert, lName: Anderson, age:42},

{fName: Albert, lName: Anderson, age:41},

{fName: Albert, lName: Bernard, age:42}]
```

Would return true, as the first and second objects have same fName and lName.

My first thought was to create a `Set` that would take an object containing only the `fName` and `lName` pair, insert each pair into the `Set` with a for loop, and compare the size of the `Set` to the size of the array to see if there are duplicates. I was wondering if there is a faster or better way to do this

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and exit the loop if a same pattern is found.

```js
function hasSame(array) {
    const getValueBy = keys => object => keys.map(k => object[k]).join('|');

    var seen = new Set,
        getV = getValueBy(['fName', 'lName']);

     return array.some(o => seen.has(getV(o)) || !seen.add(getV(o)));
}

var data = [{ fName: 'Albert', lName: 'Anderson', age: 42 }, { fName: 'Albert', lName: 'Anderson', age: 41 }, { fName: 'Albert', lName: 'Bernard', age: 42 }];

console.log(hasSame(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over array and in every iteration iterate over array again to compare, count will be at least 1, because there will be same object Everytime, so if there are more matches, count will be more than 1

```
for(let obj of arr) {
    let count = 0
    for(let obj2 of arr) {
        if(obj.fName == obj2.fName && obj.lName == obj2.lName) count++
    }
    if(count > 1) return true
}
return false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` and `while` loop

- Initialize `newMap` as `Map` to keep track of `fName` and `lName`
- Initialize `dup` as false to keep track when to stop loop
- Loop over the array, check if `fName-lName` is already present in `newMap` then set `dup` to true,
- If not than carry on loop and keep adding values to `newMap` upto the last element of array

```js
let obj = [{fName: 'Albert',lName: 'Anderson',age: 42},{fName: 'Albert',lName: 'Anderson',age: 41},{fName: 'Albert',lName: 'Bernard',age: 42}]

let findIsDup = (obj) => {
  let newMap = new Map()
  let dup = false
  let index = 0
  while (!dup && index < obj.length) {
    let {fName,lName} = obj[index]
    let key = fName+ '-' + lName
    if (newMap.has(key)) {
      dup = true
    }
    index++
    newMap.set(key, key)
  }
  return dup
}

console.log(findIsDup(obj))
console.log(findIsDup(obj.slice(1,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDuplicatedItem(arr, compareFn) {
  return arr.slice(0).reduce(([_, ...rest], item, i, reducedArr) => {
    if (!rest.some(tmp => compareFn(item, tmp))) {
      return rest.length ? rest : false;
    }

    reducedArr.splice(0); // clean arr to "break" reduce
    return item;
  }, arr);
}

const arr = [
  { fName: "Albert", lName: "Anderson", age: 42 },
  { fName: "Albert", lName: "Anderson", age: 41 },
  { fName: "Albert", lName: "Bernard", age: 43 }
];

const isSameFullName = (a, b) => a.fName == b.fName && a.lName == b.lName;
const duplicatedItem = getDuplicatedItem(arr, isSameFullName)
console.log(duplicatedItem) // { fName: 'Albert', lName: 'Anderson', age: 42 }

const isSameAge = (a, b) => a.age == b.age
const notFound = getDuplicatedItem(arr, isSameAge)
console.log(notFound) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the good old `for` loop and a little help from the inbuilt `Array.prototype.some()` function.

You first iterate through each object in the array to use them as argument(or in this case - search key) for the `some()` function. The `some()`function then uses this object key to match each object in the array except itself.

The advantage of the `some()` function is that when a match is found the iteration through the array halts immediately and returns `true`. We can then use this condition to terminate the outer `for` loop.

```js
var persons = [{fName: 'Albert', lName: 'Anderson', age:42}, {fName: 'Albert', lName: 'Anderson', age:41}, {fName: 'Albert', lName: 'Bernard', age:42}];

console.log(hasDuplicate(persons));

function hasDuplicate(persons) {
    for(var i=0; i<persons.length; i++) {
        var isDuplicate = persons.some(function(duplicate, index) {
            return i !== index && duplicate.fName === persons[i].fName && duplicate.lName === persons[i].lName
        });
        if (isDuplicate) return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```